# lftp mirror downloads-distro.mongodb.org looping on fetching headers

Tags: linux, mongodb, mirror, lftp

We recently updated a linux/Centos mirror server that we use for updating internal linux machines.

we are using the mrepo command to do the updates which runs the following `lftp` command.

```
exec /usr/bin/lftp -d -c '; mirror -c -P -v -v -v -e -I *.rpm -X 
    "/headers/" -X "/repodata/" -X "*.src.rpm" -X "/SRPMS/" -X 
    "*-debuginfo-*.rpm" -X "/debug/" http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org
    /repo/redhat/os/x86_64/ /var/mrepo/10gen-x86_64/10gen; quit'
```

*broken up in multiple line for readability*

however this process is hanging for a number of our repos.  This only started after we updated the internal mirror server to the CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

here is the output with the `-d` switch on.

Any ideas on why this is happening?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
---- Connecting to downloads-distro.mongodb.org (23.23.96.15) port 80
---- Sending request...
**** Hit EOF while fetching headers
---- Closing HTTP connection
---- Connecting to downloads-distro.mongodb.org (23.23.96.15) port 80
---- Sending request...
**** Hit EOF while fetching headers
---- Closing HTTP connection
---- Connecting to downloads-distro.mongodb.org (23.23.96.15) port 80
---- Sending request...
**** Hit EOF while fetching headers
---- Closing HTTP connection
---- Connecting to downloads-distro.mongodb.org (23.23.96.15) port 80
---- Sending request...
repodata: Getting files information (100%) [Waiting for response...]
```

Comment: Thanks  Mpaskov for helping make that more readible.     One other thing to mention is that if I remove the  -I *.rpm from the above lftp command it works and does not hang.       Im not sure why that makes a difference.

Comment: You can increase verbosity to see the http request. I can guess that mirror -c option may cause the server misbehavior.

Comment: I tried the mirror command without the -c and still get a hang.  After removing the -I *.rpm we get a bit further in our mrepo update but now see hanging again while fetching headers.                                                                                  **** Hit EOF while fetching headers
---- Closing HTTP connection
---- Connecting to mirror.centos.org (66.241.106.181) port 80
---- Sending request...
Packages: Getting files information (100%) [Waiting for response...]